# IntelliJ, running glassfish in debug mode, Artifact not being deployed

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, glassfish

System: Mac OS

IntelliJ: 2016.1.4

Glassfish: 4.1.1 (build 1)

JDK: jdk1.8.0.0_91.jdk

Java: JavaEE 7

IntelliJ cannot run glassfish in debug mode. Initially debug mode ran fine: although port (9009) needed to be killed ever now and then.

Every time glassfish is started in --debug mode (from IntelliJ) the application hangs at: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...

Passed environment variables:

*JAVA_OPTS -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:9009,suspend=y,server=n*

Please see screen shots attached

- [for debug output log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nL8Jr.png)
- [for glassfish attached process log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iGMI.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

current checks:

- start intellij with sudo
- reinstall glassfish
- change debug port

Answer (score 0):

Change `suspend=y` to `suspend=n` so your `JAVA_OPTS` looks like this:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:9009,suspend=n,server=n
```

When `suspend` is set to `y`, it suspends during startup and waits until a debugger is connected to continue processing. You may also want to remove the IP address so that you aren't binding to localhost:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=9009,suspend=n,server=n
```

I'm not sure if that would actually cause problems, but it's not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mike. After reading an article on run time configurations from jetbrains: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/run-debug-configuration-glassfish-server.html  - The server configurations can only be modified in the domain.xml config file. Which didn't alleviate the problem. After running a simple servlet application in debug mode with no issues, there must be an issue which my application. This will be one of those scenarios where I will have to tear down the application piece by piece until I can make sense of it. Thanks for your time, always appreciated!

Comment: Did you make sure to add the `domain.xml` change to the `server-config`, not just the `default-config`? It's a common mistake to make when editing the domain.xml directly. The `default-config` looks exactly the same as the `server-config`, but is ignored (it's a template, whereas the `server-config` is the config belonging to the default server)

Comment: I am sorry but could anyone help me out with how to add the above configuration to java_opts to enable debugging in glassfish ?

Comment: @BurhanShakir ask as a new question and paste a link here. Then I can answer on your new question - it's hard to be clear in the comments section.

Comment: @Mike Sure , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50860570/remote-debugging-in-glassfish-using-intellij